# Comparing element in string with length-1 string in C++

Tags: c++, types

I am sorry for the simple question, but I cannot understand why this simple program does not work.

What is `a[0]` supposed to be other than `"a"`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string a = "abcd";
    string b = "a";


    if (a[0]==b){//<------problem here
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which returns the error

> no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘char’ and ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’)

or simply using `string c=a[0];` returns the error:

> conversion from ‘char’ to non-scalar type ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ requested

PS: after trying a few things, I can get it to work if I compare `a[0]==b[0]` or assign `c[0]=a[0]` because those are now definitely the same type, but I still would like to know what the standard and/or fastest way to carry out a comparison of a substring with another string in C++ is.

Comment: `what is a[0] supposed to be other than "a"?`  Well, it could be the character `'a'`.

Comment: That works fine, because they are the same type, but I want to test if a substring like a[0]==b and it fails because they are of different types. So what type is a[0]?

Comment: Are you looking for a general sub-string of any length in a string or are you trying to quickly find is a sub-string of length of exactly 1 is in a string?  The 2nd case is akin to looking for a `char` in a string.

Comment: A `std::string` is a string of `char`, so any index into the `string` will be a `char`

Comment: After looking at all the replies, my question is now why if I define char c="a"; a[0]==c; returns an error if a[0] is char.

Comment: `"a"` is not a `char`, it's a `const char *`. `'a'` is a `char` (note the different quotes - double vs single).

Comment: Ok, I know now the difference: a[0]=='c' (single quotes matters). Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is a[0] supposed to be other than "a"?

It is an `'a'` not `"a"` and it is a `char`. You cannot compare a `char` to a `string` because they are different types. But what you can do is extract a substring from your string that is the length of 1 character:

```
if (a.substr(0,1)==b)...
```

Then you will be comparing `"a"` to `"a"` because `.substr` returns a `string` not a `char`, even if the length is 1.

Also don't forget to `#include <string>` if you are working with `std::string`.

Comment: Bit of overkill there.  `a[0] == b[0]` would be a bit more direct. The gold standard would probably be to make `b` a `char`, though.

Comment: @user4581301 While it may be so, and I agree with you, OP seems to be interested in comparing strings.

Comment: Thanks, that finally solved it for me (in my code and in my head), a[0]='a'. I need to be more careful to distinguish "a" from 'a' in the future.

Answer (score 6):

You should use **std::string::find** to find substrings. Using the subscript operator on string returns a single character (scalar), not a string (vector, non-scalar); therefore, they are not the same type and there is no defined comparison.

You can can also use **std::string::substr** to select a substring which you can directly compare against another string.

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int
main() {
    std::string a = "abcd";
    std::string b = "a";
    if (a.find(b) != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << a << "\n";
    }
    if (a.substr(0, 1) == b) {
        std::cout << a << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**References**

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: Perhaps also mention [std::string::substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), as well as the fact that `"foo"` is of type `const char *` (a pointer to a `\0` terminated string) whereas `'f'` is of type `char` (single character). Additionally, I would personally recommend linking to cppreference.com rather than cplusplus.com for a higher quality reference site.

Answer (score 0):

`a[0]` is a character, which has the value `'a'`, whereas `b` is a string, which has a different type. This will work if an `operator ==(char, string)` is defined (or some variant with `const`'s and/or ref's) but there isn't, at least in the C++ standard, so the compilation *should* fail. The clang compiler even gives the helpful message,

> invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'string'...

which indicates that you're comparing different types.

Try changing it to compare `a[0]` and `b[0]`. [The bracket operator is defined for strings, and returns a character](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/), so you can compare them that way.

*edit:* This may look as if it doesn't answer the question. It **does** answer the original question; the OP changed the entirety of the question after the fact (and someone added a corresponding answer) but the original question is still there in the first paragraph. I'll delete the answer if moderators want.

Comment: I'd call the error message received slightly more direct: "operand types are ‘char’ and ‘std::__cxx11::string".

Comment: That's helpful, yet I also tried defining char c="a", but a[0]==c also returns an error (invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]), so a[0] is not a char, as I would have expected.

Comment: @user4581301 I reckon that's different compiler's message; I pointed out that mine was clang.

Comment: @jpf137 Au contraire, `a[0]` **is** a `char`; it's `c` that isn't. Whenever you use double quotes, you get a `char *`.

Comment: @user4581301 Also, I'd point out that the compiler error mentioned has the unsightly, albeit common, qualifications that help make certain compilers' messages unreadable to novices: `std::__cxx11::string` instead of just plain `string`.

Comment: It's the error message presented to the asker as stated in their question. I'm not a big fan of the `__cxx11`, but I don't think `int` in place of `char` is better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use b='a'; and this should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).